# Facilitating class communication c++

Tags: c++, class

I have am writing a game and have a main class called GameManager. I want it to be as abstract as possible. Inside it, it has objects of other classes, Player, and ItemManager. Imagine I have a function in player which detects if the player is in a certain area (checking x and y values). If for instance, I wanted to spawn an item createItem() if the player is in that area. How would I facilitate communication between the classes?

Comment: You want something like an event based system ? "onPlayerEnters(Area enemyZone) { do this; } kind of thing ?

Comment: Although you haven't described them in enough detail to say with any certainty, your `ItemManager` and (especially) `GameManager` sound suspiciously as if you may have a tendency toward God Classes.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).  In that pattern there is a subject that maintains a list of observers.  When the state of the subject changes it notifies the observers, who are free to react as they deem appropriate.  In this case the Player is your subject and the GameManager is an observer.  When Player's location changes, it notifies GameManager, who can then spawn an item or take some other action.

Comment: But how would Player send information backwards to the GameManager and then alert it to tell the class ItemManager what to do? That's my question. Thanks!

Comment: Satchmo: Chris has answered your question.  If you follow the link to the observer pattern description on Wikipedia you may get more of the implementation details, but summarily the idea is that the Player class provides a subscribe member function accepting say a function pointer, which it can store and call on events that might interest subscribers.  The GameManager registers one of its functions, which then calls into the ItemManager to do whatever it needs to to it.

Answer (score 0):

The way i'm currently trying to do it is to define an abstract base class (dubbed 'Commando') that has a virtual function Command(string cmd), and having every game-related object (and manager of objects) inherit from that, and override Command() with code to parse strings of text (or in the case of the managers, parse or truncate and pass along to sub-objects contained in maps); this approach has limitations, but it works for my purposes.

```
command.h:
class Commando
{
public:
  virtual int Command(std::string const& cmd) = 0;
};

atom.h:
#include "command.h"

class Atom : public Commando
{
public:
  int Command(std::string const& cmd);
};
```

Comment: This really solves a parallel problem, not the one he's trying to solve. Making GameManager, ItemManager, and Player all inherit Commando means they have a way to communicate once they can find each other—but how do they find each other? Does the player have a bunch of members like Commando *gameManager_, *itemManager, etc.? Or use some kind of broker? Or use the observer pattern? Or…? As the OP said in his comment on Chris Hayden's answer, that's the part he's looking for help on. (I'm also not sure why you need the flexibility of a text protocol, but don't need dynamic connections…)

Comment: I use a bunch of global definitions for the managers, and the EventMgr is the one in charge of referring inter-Manager command strings to their target Managers.